# Correct way to prevent methods to run if method1 doesn't complete

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to C# and trying to figure out the correct way to prevent method `Image.insert` to run if `Image.Create` returns without completing.

The problem I'm having is that in `Image.Create`, I get a question about the name, and if the name already exists, it returns but the circle and square are created in the already existing painting.

I can get it to work with bool and if statments, but there has to be a better way and I want to learn it.

```
namespace Painting
{
    private void BTNa4_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image.Create("A4", "Green", new double[] { 207, 165});
        Image.Insert("Circle", new double[] { 0, 0}, 0);
        Image.Insert("Square", new double[] { 20, 20}, 45);
    }
}
```

*Edited to clarify
Image.Create doesnt throw any exception at the moment, it only returns even if the name I input is already in use or exiting out of it. (can always be change if recommended).

"I get a question about the name" I meant I get asked to name the picturefile.

```
 public class Image
{
    public static void Create(string _size, string _color ,double[] _pos)
{
do stuff
}

public static void insert(string _blockname, double[] _pos, int _angle)
{
do other stuff
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: What is wrong with `bool` and `if` statements? Why are they not good enough? They very well could be the better way compared to whatever other idea you or others might come up, no? Aside from this, asking for "better ways" is asking for highly opinionated answers, with different people having a different understanding of what constitutes "better". Thus, such opinion-based questions are usually off-topic for SO...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you clarify exactly what you mean by "returns without completing"? Does it throw an exception? Return any other error indication? What do you mean by "I get a question about the name"? Which `Image` class is this? I'm afraid your question is too unclear to answer at the moment. If you could edit it to be clearer, hopefully we'll be in a better position to help.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with bool and ifstatments but just want my code to be as clean and efficient as possible, maybe Im just over complication things but how else are you suppose to get better. And no idea if the results after my searches are the right way to go(CancellationToken, threading or exception)

Comment: I would say that you need to use create instances of `Image` instead of using static methods if you want to achieve clean and efficient code. You may also want to use constructor instead of `Create` and throw exceptions, if something goes wrong. This way you will not have classes in an invalid state.